# Height of Binary Tree StackOverflow Exception

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I am trying to find the height of a binary search tree in Java. Here is my `getHeight()` function.

```
public int getHeight(RedBlackTree<E> n) {
    if (n == EMPTY || n == null) // line 427
        return -1;
    return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(n.left), getHeight(n.right)); // line 429
}
```

I keep getting a StackOverflow exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at RedBlackTree.getHeight(RedBlackTree.java:427)
    at RedBlackTree.getHeight(RedBlackTree.java:429)
    at RedBlackTree.getHeight(RedBlackTree.java:429)
    at RedBlackTree.getHeight(RedBlackTree.java:429)
    at RedBlackTree.getHeight(RedBlackTree.java:429)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Note: My tree is very large so maybe that's why?

Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: And how high *is* your tree? Note that if it's badly constructed and contains a cycle, that would certainly cause a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. I would know if the function worked haha.

Comment: Well how is the tree being constructed? Do you have test cases to see whether *they* work? (If not, now would be a great time to start testing...)

Comment: If this is supposed to be a red-black tree, this is _definitely_ a symptom that your tree is being balanced or constructed incorrectly.  A correctly balanced red-black tree big enough to overflow the stack like this would have to be unimaginably large, and you'd run out of memory before you ran out the stack.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It is a red-black tree.

Comment: @Nic It might be supposed to be, but what I'm saying is that your stack trace is strong evidence that it's not a correct red black tree.  Based on the Wikipedia page for red black trees, the height of the root is >= 2^(h/2) - 1.  Java probably wouldn't stack overflow for a stack depth of less than 1000, so if your red black tree implementation was correct, your tree would have at least 10^150 elements, or over 10 billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion elements.  I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: Er, correction: the number of elements in a correct red black tree of size h according to Wikipedia is >= 2^(h/2) - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this could happen when your tree is very tall: each invocation of `getHeight` creates a stack frame, so you are running a risk of exhausting the stack for very tall trees.

This could also happen if your graph has a *cycle*, meaning that it is not, in fact, a tree. You can test if this is the case by storing all vertices of the tree that you visited so far in a `HashSet`. If you see a vertex for the second time during the computation of tree height, you have a graph with a cycle.

One approach to fixing stack overflow problem is to use your own collection, a stack or a queue, to compute the height in an iterative way.

Answer (score 0):

I answer for this channel because as comment is already a little long.

It seems strange that you have a stack overflow since you're using red black trees, as its height is bounded to 2 log(n + 1)   (binary log)

As a concrete case, the maximum height of a tree of 100 million of keys would

```
2*log(1e8 + 1)/log(2) ~ 54 rounded to ceil.
```

54 stack frames is not too much, except if you are using a restricted hardware, vm, etc and/or your routines receive many parameters and use many local variables.

So, the first thing I would do is to check whether your routines in effect receive or produce correct red black trees